# Eclipse - Mylyn window trim active task displayed multiple times

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I have found a solution to this but I'll post the question in case anyone else (or me in the future) gets this problem as it took me ages to find the solution and hopefully I can save someone else the time.

In Eclipse, the Mylyn plugin allows the currently active task to be displayed on the window trim.
I have the problem that sometimes this window trim item gets displayed multiple times.
I think it may be after Eclipse crashes.

It took me a while to find the solution but in your Eclipse workspace directory if you go to
`/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/` you will find the workbench config file `workbench.xmi`.

**Make a backup of this file in case anything goes wrong.**

Search for the string `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.dropdown`
which should be somewhere in a `<trimBars>` element.

You should see three sections which have been duplicated multiple times,
1:

```
<children xsi:type="menu:DirectMenuItem" xmi:id="_-m5l4KFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.dropdown">
    <tags>Rendered</tags>
</children>
```

2:

```
<children xsi:type="menu:RenderedMenuItem" xmi:id="_-m5l8qFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.dropdown"/>
```

3:

```
<children xsi:type="menu:ToolControl" xmi:id="_-m5mCqFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.control" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution"> <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.control"/>
      <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_-m5mC6FYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" coreExpressionId="programmatic.value"/>
    </children>
    <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_-m5mDKFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim" visible="false" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/etool16/navigate-previous.gif" command="_-m7cDKFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ">
      <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim"/>
      <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_-m5mDaFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" coreExpressionId="programmatic.value"/>
      <menu xmi:id="_-m5mDqFYEeS9VLGCzhAhMQ" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim"/>
    </children>
```

Remove all duplicates and restart Eclipse, the duplicated trim bar task display should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do the following as described in this [eclipse bug comment here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413492#c5) - after saving your perspectives, establish a fresh workspace window using ...

1. Window > New Window
2. Close old window
3. File > Restart

Comment: Still a workaround but easier than editing files, a useful thread to follow, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jörg, still annoying but preferable to editing files.

Answer (score 2):

This has bugged me for a long time! The solution that the OP added to the question didn't work out for me, but it did inspire me to play around with the `workbench.xmi` file. The following solution ended up working for me in Eclipse Mars:

1. In the Eclipse Preferences pane for Mylyn, under "Tasks", untick *"Show active task on window trim"*
2. Shut down Eclipse normally
3. Open `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` in a text editor, and find the `<trimBars>` element that describes the trim that contains the `<children>` item for the unwanted Mylyn task widget (mine had an `elementId` of `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.container`; I'm using Mylyn Tasks 3.16.0.v20150609-0543)
4. Delete the entire `<children>` element describing the task widget and save the file
5. Start Eclipse normally
6. Back in the preferences pane for Mylyn, re-enable *"Show active task on window trim"* in "Tasks"
7. Restart Eclipse

The following block is what I ended up deleting:

```xml
  <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar" xmi:id="_d-lsazctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.container">
    <tags>Draggable</tags>
    <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_d-lsbDctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/icons/etool16/navigate-previous.gif" command="_d-nkeTctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q">
      <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim"/>
      <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_d-lsbTctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" coreExpressionId="programmatic.value"/>
      <menu xmi:id="_d-lsbjctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim"/>
    </children>
    <children xsi:type="menu:ToolControl" xmi:id="_d-lsbzctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" elementId="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.control" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution">
      <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.trim.control"/>
      <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:CoreExpression" xmi:id="_d-lscDctEeW6RMhi_xmN_Q" coreExpressionId="programmatic.value"/>
    </children>
  </children>
```

This is probably more faff than just creating a new window and closing the original, but I found that a lot of minor things like column widths didn't get carried over to the new window.